# Refactoring a large block of chained if-else statements

Tags: jquery

This seems like overkill and I would like to refactor this...any suggestions

```
    if($(this).text() == "Grocery"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "gro");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Restaurant"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "res");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Bar"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "bar");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Pizza Delivery"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "piz");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Quick Service"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "qui");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Retail"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "ret");
    }else if($(this).text() == "Salon"){
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", "sal");
    }
    if($(this).attr("id").slice(-1) == 1){
        $(".number_changer").attr("id", "one1");
    }else if($(this).attr("id").slice(-1) == 2){
        $(".number_changer").attr("id", "two2");
    }else if($(this).attr("id").slice(-1) == 3){
        $(".number_changer").attr("id", "three3");
    }else if($(this).attr("id").slice(-1) == 4){
        $(".number_changer").attr("id", "four4");
    }else if($(this).attr("id").slice(-1) == 5){
        $(".number_changer").attr("id", "five5");}
```

Comment: That would be alright (in terms of performance, not programmer sanity ;) if you had cached the `id` and `text`, if not you're just creating a new jQuery object for *every one of those `if` statements!*

Comment: related: [Alternative to a million IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029089/alternative-to-a-million-if-statements)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look here,

```
if($(this).text() == "Grocery"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "gro");
}else if($(this).text() == "Restaurant"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "res");
}else if($(this).text() == "Bar"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "bar");
}else if($(this).text() == "Pizza Delivery"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "piz");
}else if($(this).text() == "Quick Service"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "qui");
}else if($(this).text() == "Retail"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "ret");
}else if($(this).text() == "Salon"){
    $(".type_changer").attr("id", "sal");
}
```

You have to think all the repetitions away. What would left over? Right, the text and id values:

```
"Grocery", "gro"
"Restaurant", "res"
"Bar", "bar"
"Pizza Delivery", "piz"
"Quick Service", "qui"
"Retail", "ret"
"Salon", "sal"
```

Let hold them in some data structure. An object is an obvious choice.

```
var types = {
    "Grocery": "gro",
    "Restaurant": "res",
    "Bar": "bar",
    "Pizza Delivery": "piz",
    "Quick Service": "qui",
    "Retail": "ret",
    "Salon": "sal"
}
```

It can be accessed like an associative array with dynamic keys. Now you can use a single line:

```
$(".type_changer").attr("id", types[$(this).text()]);
```

How to replace the second part is left as exercise to you, but it boils down to the same.

---

**Update**: you seem to have a [hard time in understanding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642089/can-someone-walk-me-through-this-line). Here's an explanation from my side:

When `$(this).text()` returns `"Grocery"`, the above will resolve to

```
$(".type_changer").attr("id", types["Grocery"]);
```

The `types["Grocery"]` will in turn return `"gro"`, so it basically ends up as

```
$(".type_changer").attr("id", "gro");
```

when `$(this).text()` is `"Grocery"`.

#### See also:

- [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: I was writing something along these lines, and then I saw the evil orange bar at the top of viewport telling me that an answer had been posted, and that BalusC had won.

Comment: @Karim: That occurs me too often during a normal working day in the jQuery tag. That's why I have practically given up answering it during working days and almost only answer it during weekends, then there's a *bit* more chance that no one else has posted a suitable answer yet ;)

Answer (score 2):

started writing pseudocode for a switch statement, then thought of this :

```
//make your 2D array (or key->value pair if you like)
var hash = [ ["Grocery","gro"],
             ["Restaurant","res"],
             //etc....
           ];

//loop thru your text(), checking to see if it matches any 0th item in your hash
foreach(e in hash) {
    if($(this).text() == hash[e][0] {
        //aha! match found
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", hash[e][1]);
    }

}

//disclaimer : untested code, but you should get the gist of it from this
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an array that contains the value (eg: Salon, Grocery) and also contains the replacement (eg: sal, gro) and replace with that. The alternative is to simply take the first 3 letters and lowercase them *but* this may cause issues with things that contain only 2 letters then a space if we assume you'll be expanding the list, if not you can go with simply lowercasing the first 3 letters. If you need code examples, just say :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **class instead of id** as inner wrapper

use array to store your custom text for matching later

> $('.selector').each(function() {}

in this way you can make process common

use array replace method

```
from = ['Grocery','Restaurant']
to = ['gro','res']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textToVal =
{
    "Grocery" : "gro",
    "Restaurant" : "res"
    // and so on ...
};

for (var text in textToVal) {
    if ($(this).text() == text)
        $(".type_changer").attr("id", textToVal[text]);
}
```