# Can someone walk me through this line

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

```
var types = {
  "Grocery": "gro",
  "Restaurant": "res",
  "Bar": "bar",
  "Pizza Delivery": "piz",
  "Quick Service": "qui",
  "Retail": "ret",
  "Salon": "sal"
}

$(".type_changer").attr("id", types[$(this).text()]);
```

I understand that the class `type_changer` id is being changed to the part of this array but I don't understand `types[$(this).text()]`

and this line

```
$(this).parents('.select-holder').find('.text').text($(this).text());
```

seems almost understandable but I get confused on the `.parents` and the `.find('.text').text($(this).text());`

Comment: I suppose it'll be nice to note the source of that above piece of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640843/there-has-got-to-be-a-cleaner-way-to-do-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(this).text()` takes the text of the current element (the `<li>` you're looping over in your case, unless your markup has changed).

It then uses that text as the key on the `types` object, basically doing `types["Grocery"]` when you click the "Grocery" link for example.

In JavaScript you can do `types.Grocery` or `types["Grocery"]` to access the property, which has a value of `"gro"`.

---

The last statement is taking that same "Grocery" test and setting it as the text for the `class="text"` element in the parent.

Comment: But won't that make all `.type_changer` elements have the same id, which is the corresponding value of the current element `.text()`? Because `this` is evaluated where it is called, not on every element:  `$(".type_changer").attr("id", types[$(this).text()]);`

Comment: @aularon - There's a bit of context missing in the question, this happens inside a loop over the `<li>` elements :)

Comment: If anyone's curious how to do this outside that loop though, then it would be: `$(".type_changer").attr("id", function() { return types[$(this).text()]; });`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).text()` will get the text inside the current DOM element and it will use this text to  find the corresponding value in the array (for example `types['Restaurant']`).

Answer (score 1):

On every element that has class 'type-changer', change it's ID to the value mapped in `types` to the text in the element, eg.

```
<div class="type-changer">Salon</div>
```

would be converted to

```
<div class="type-changer" id="sal">Salon</div>
```