# Updating credit card logos based on user input via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am creating a credit card page for my mobile website. I want that as soon as I enter the number, say, 5, the image in input box should be of maestro-card, entering 4 changes the image to be that of some other card, and so on.  Much as the Clear Trip mobile site does.

I used JavaScript's `onkeypress` event but it receives an action when there is no value is in the text box.

```
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" style="width:80%"  onkeypress="func();"/> <div class="card-img"></div>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Since you are asking rather basic things i really hope you won't prompt for the user's credit card number, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `keyup` and `input` events.

Answer (score -1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksHa2/12/

```
<div class="card-img"><img id="img" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/laborday12-hp.jpg"/></div>

<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" style="width:80%" onkeydown="update(this);" onchange="update(this);"/>

<script>
    function update( object )
    {
        if ( object.value.length == 1 )
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/ramon_y_cajal-2012-hp.jpg";
        }
        else if ( object.value.length == 2 )
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/queensday12-hp.jpg";
        }
        else if ( object.value.length == 3 )
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/queensday12-hp.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/laborday12-hp.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
​
```

Comment: I want the change to happens as i enter the number.In your case as i enter 1 i should get that image not when text box goes out of focus!

Comment: You might need to read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10029116/1048572) on the question "Alternative to a million IF statements"... Your function in one line: `document.getElementById('img').src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/" + ["ramon_y_cajal-2012-hp", "queensday12-hp", "queensday12-hp", "laborday12-hp"][object.value.length-1] + ".jpg";`