# Inserting Element Based on a Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert different url's dynamically after checking a condition

Here's the pseudocode

```
If div.id = "abc" then
create url <a href="www.zzz.html"'>Cosmetics</a>');
Append url to div

else if div.id = "xyz" then
create url <a href="www.abc.html"'>LEather goods</a>');
Append url to div

else if div.id = "mno" then
create url <a href="www.kkk.html"'>Diapers</a>');
Append url to div
```

and so on.

How can I write this in JavaScript/jQUery. How to handle the code efficiently if there are 15 such If-Else conditions.

This code is not looking good

```
if $("#abc) then

 var dynLink = $('<a href=zzz.html"'>Cosmetics</a>');
    $("#abc").append(dynLink);

else if $("#xyz")
 var dynLink = $('<a href=abc.html"'>LEather</a>');
    $("#xyz").append(dynLink);
```

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to a million IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029089/alternative-to-a-million-if-statements) - I've posted a general answer there (covering all the answers here :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var link = [
    ["#abc", "#wfh", "http://www.123.com", "Maine"],
    ["#123", "#qwe", "http://www.abc.com", "Texas"]
];

$.each(link, function(e) {
    $(link[e][0] + "," + link[e][1])
        .append("<a href='" + link[e][2] + "'>" + link[e][3] + "</a>");
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yvuvh/5/

---

This is just simply setting up the links and titles in the array, and a `for` loop is searching through the array to see if it can find a `div` with any of those `id`'s, and if so, then append the appropriate link.

To add more, just add another `array` to the `link` array, like so:

```
var link = [
    ["#abc", "#wfh", "http://www.123.com", "Maine" ],
    ["#123", "#qwe", "http://www.abc.com", "Texas" ],
    ["#xyz", "#zyx", "http://www.yzx.com", "Mexico"]
];​
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance but where are you checking the ID of each div before inserting a link in it?

Comment: Oh I now understand the code. This is beautiful. How can I mark two answers correct? I upvoted you :)

Comment: just one more question - how can I add an 'OR' condition..like if div.id = abc OR div.id = 123 then // do this

Comment: @Gorgeous You can't unfortunately. So just always remember to mark the answer you feel most comfortable with and answers the question. :)

Comment: I just updated your code but "wfh" does not work. Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/Yvuvh/1/

Comment: @Gorgeous Updated answer. Try the new link above.

Comment: @Shaz: Passing a function (which returns undefined in the most cases) to append() for each link array is not a good solution in here.

Comment: @Bergi How's the new solution then? Less `Undefined` happening.

Comment: Bergi what does that mean, please explain in simple language

Comment: @Shaz: Better. You could further improve it by allowing different numbers of ids - just make it one selector at the first array index.

Answer (score 1):

```
if $("#abc) then

 var dynLink = $('<a href=zzz.html"'>Cosmetics</a>');
    $("#abc").append(dynLink);

else if $("#xyz")
 var dynLink = $('<a href=abc.html"'>LEather</a>');
    $("#xyz").append(dynLink);
```

▲ That is *not* valid JavaScript.

---

▼ This is [how you do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) when you have a *bunch* of `if-then`s:

```
switch(div.id){
    case "abc":
        $('<a href="zzz.html">Cosmetics</a>').appendTo("div#whateveritis");
        break;
    case "xyx":
        $('<a href="abc.html">Leather</a>').appendTo("div#whateveritis");
        break;
    case "more more more":
        //same stuff here.
        break;
    default:
        //default
        break;
}
```

Very self-explanatory for beginners. `;)`

Seriously, you should start looking through stuff in [image: MDN] [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/). It is a good place for JavaScript references and demos (examples).

Comment: Derek thanks for first showing me some code and then providing a link where I can learn to write this kinda code. I will study the switch-case statement in detail. This looks similar to what I have used in Java

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that contains all of these relationships, like this:

```
var links = {
    'abc': { link:'foo.html', text:'Foo Link' },
    'xyz': { link:'bar.html', text:'Bar Link' }
};
```

Then we'll add a couple `div` elements to test this out:

```
​<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="xyz"></div>​​​​​​​​​​
<div id="foo"></div>
```

And lastly our jQuery which should add some links for us:

```
$("div").append(function(){
    var link = links[this.id];
    return link ? $("<a>", { href:link.href, html:link.text }) : "n/a" ;
});​​​
```

This cycles over all of our `div` elements, checking to see if their `id` is found within our `links` object. If it is, then we place a link within that `div` that has the appropriate properties. If we don't find that `id` within our object, we simply append "n/a" to the `div`.

```
<div id="abc"><a href="foo.html">Foo Link</a></div>
<div id="xyz"><a href="bar.html">Bar Link</a></div>
<div id="foo">n/a</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vFjSw/

Comment: Jonathan, a very good solution, but performance wise how do I determine if your solution or Shaz solution performs better?

Answer (score 0):

Put the div.id's in an associate array that maps to the target URL, then just look it up by key.  One hashed lookup beats a linear number of if/else-if comparisons *if* you only have to load it once for each lookup...

This strikes me as more "elegant" or readable or maintainable regardless of micro-performance.  It's not obvious to me which of make array v. run if/else if's is faster, you'll have to profile.  If however, you 1) must optimize for time, and 2) only expect one use of this code for each time the page is loaded, the best you can do is put the url's you expect toward the top of the if/elif block.  Be sure to comment exactly that you're doing this so future dev doesn't alphabetize them.

Comment: thanks but I am so new to scripts that it went over my head..can you show some code please

Comment: Why are you here on StackOverflow then? This is a place where beginners like me can learn right? And I did try, not a homework I am asking you to do.