# split a sum into array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a dice function that trows random dices and sum the value of them.

Now every number from 0-9 is connected to a class, so if i get number 4 it should call class " four"
So i created a switch from 0-9 .
But when i get a sum more than 9 its give me the default number, since the function dosent know that 11 is actually 2 numbers. 
I was wonder I its possible to split the numbers and put them into an array so when i pass it to the switch it gets med "one" "one" .

Any ideas ?

```
var value = total;
    switch(this.value){
        case 1:
            value ="one";
            break
        case 2:
            value ="two";
            break
        case 3:
            value ="three";
            break
        case 4:
            value ="four";
            break
        case 5:
            value ="five";
            break
        case 6:
            value ="six";
            break
        case 7:
            value ="seven";
            break
        case 8:
            value ="eight";
            break
        case 9:
            value ="nine";
            break
        case 0:
            value ="zero";
            break
        default:
            value ="zero" 
    }
```

Comment: well, its more like.
When i get the sum 11, I would like to call the switch by class "one" + "one" otherwise i would need a endless combinations of numbers to call every sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [string `split` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for that:

```
var result = this.value.toString(10).split("").map(function(digit) {
    return ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"][digit];
});
```

(Of course you can use a loop instead of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map); Check [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11232189/1048572) on how the array thing works)

Comment: @Dymond: Ah, wait, you're neither switching on the `total` nor on the `value` variable, but on the `this.value` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) after you transformed your number to a string. Then run through the resulting array and assign your classes.

```
var total = 11;

var pieces = ("" + total).split( "" );

for( var i=0; i<pieces.length; i++) {
  // your switch in here
}
```

Comment: It almost work :)
when i do a console.log the log from pieces is ["3"] ["4"] I need to remove the "" dots. is it possible to just print the numbers separly without the dots and squere bracket

Comment: @Dymond Easiest way would be to change the condition in your `switch` clause to use `+this,value` instead of just `value`. Or you change the case statements to use strings instead of numbers.