# JavaScript: associating an integer with a long list of strings

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving strings from JSON and need to associate them with an integer.  So for example I currently use this method:

```
var foo = "This is my string";
var bar;

if (foo === "This is my string"){
   bar = 3000;
} else if (foo === "Some other string"){
   bar = 30001;
}
```

The problem is that I have ~50 strings I need to associate, and it seems like this huge block of if/else statements can be done in a more efficient way.

Is there any way to make these associations in a more concise and efficient manner?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an object, like this:

```
dict = {
     "This is my string": 3000,
     "Some other string": 30001,
     etc
}

bar = dict[foo]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a map:

```
var lookup = {
    "This is my string": 3000,
    "Some other string": 30001
};
```

And set `bar` to the correct value in the table:

```
var bar = lookup[foo];
```

Answer (score 1):

> See [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029116/1048572) on the possible duplicate [Alternative to a million IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10029089/1048572)

In your case, it would be something like

```
var bar = {
   "This is my string": 3000,
   "Some other string": 30001,
   ...
}[foo];
```