# Is there a way to shorten this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorter way (cleaner way really) to do the following code of mine?

```
if (whichToCheck == 1) {
    if ($('#input_3').val().length) {
        $('#error1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        hasErrors = false;
    } else {
        $('#error1').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error1').css('visibility', 'visible');
        hasErrors = true;
    }
}
else if (whichToCheck == 2) {
    if ($('#input_4').val().length) {
        $('#error2').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        hasErrors = false;
    } else {
        $('#error2').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error2').css('visibility', 'visible');
        hasErrors = true;
    }
}
else if (whichToCheck == 3) {
    if ($('#input_5').val().length) {
        $('#error3').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error3').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        hasErrors = false;
    } else {
        $('#error3').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error3').css('visibility', 'visible');
        hasErrors = true;
    }
}
else if (whichToCheck == 4) {
    if ($('#input_7_0').is(':checked')) {
        $('#error4').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error4').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        hasErrors = false;
    } else {
        $('#error4').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error4').css('visibility', 'visible');
        hasErrors = true;
    }
}
else if (whichToCheck == 5) {
    if ($('#input_6').val().length) {
        $('#error5').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error5').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        hasErrors = false;
    } else {
        $('#error5').css('display', 'block');
        $('#error5').css('visibility', 'visible');
        hasErrors = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on [Codereview.SE].

Comment: There's no good reason to set `display:none` AND `visibility:hidden`, especially if you're going to undo both at the same time.

Comment: Agreed on the below (switch block and set CSS) but also all the common properties can be set once and the changes once per block

Comment: What does your markup look like? Can you get the input corresponding to the error elements based on relations in the DOM?

Comment: Can't believe that people down vote a legit question. :0/ **Whomever down voted... post here and and convince me why it was needed.**

Comment: I didn't down vote, I even answered, but I shouldn't have. Like zzzzBov said.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should use a switch block and store the elements you want to modify in variables.
Short version:

```
var input, error;
switch(whichToCheck){
    case 1:
        input=$('#input_3');
        error=$('#error1');
        break;
    case 2:
        input=$('#input_4');
        error=$('#error2');
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
}
var hasErrors = !!input.val().length;
if(hasErrors) error.show(); else error.hide();
```

Or shorter for the end:

```
hasErrors&&error.show();
hasErrors||error.hide();
```

Comment: `hasErrors&&error.show()` is the kind of coding style that makes it completely unreadable and almost impossible to maintain

Comment: That's production code, not developement. And I disagree.

Comment: Do you mean that development code may be unreadable?

Comment: No ;-) I just don't think this specific syntax "makes code completely unreadable..."

Comment: ok maybe not "completely", just "slightly" :)

Comment: Edited my adjective from "better" to "shorter". Least I can do!

Answer (score 2):

A **much** better way to do these if..then...else statements would be to use a `switch` statement. Especially when there are multiple values that you are looking for...

```
switch(whichToCheck){
  case "1":
    // when whichToCheck == 1
  break;
  case "2":
    // when whichToCheck == 2
  break;
  default:
    // when the value of whichToCheck doesn't match any expected value
  break;
}
```

Another thing you can do to lessen the code you have is to use jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` functions to...well... hide and show elements :)  You don't really have to explicitly set the `display` and `visibility` properties.

Reference -

- [`switch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten a lot by selecting the elements dynamically. Also, put them in "cache" variables instead of recreating jQuery instances. And you can use a short form for [jQuery's `.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) by passing in an object. Also, you should put those two different styles into variables instead of repeating them - do everything to make the code more DRY.

In a one-liner:

```
$('#error'+whichToCheck).css( (hasErrors = !$('#input_'+(2+whichToCheck)).val().length)
   ? {display: 'block', visibility: 'visible'}
   : {display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden'}
);
```

However, your ids seem to be not too regular, so I recommend a mapper as in (the possible duplicate) [Alternative to a million IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029089/alternative-to-a-million-if-statements/10029116#10029116):

```
var toCheck = document.getElementById( 'input_' + {1:'3', 2:'4', 3:'5', 4:'7_0', 5:'6'}[whichToCheck] ),
    errorEl = $('#error'+whichToCheck);
hasErrors = !(toCheck.type=="checkbox" ? toCheck.checked : toCheck.value);
if (hasErrors)
    errorEl.css({display: 'block', visibility: 'visible'});
else
    errorEl.css({display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden'});
```

Also, you don't need to set `display` *and* `visibility`, and if you'd use jQuery's `.hide()`/`.show()` it would work for non-block-elements, too:

```
errorEl[hasErrors ? "show" : "hide"]();
```

Comment: Did you notice the checkbox as well in there? **if ($('#input_7_0').is(':checked')) {**

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've adapted the code.

Comment: New code does not seem to work now for the input boxes. Keeps saying true when theres nothing in the boxes.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to set `hasErrors=true` if the value is the empty string (== has no length)?

Comment: Still has it as fine without having anything in the boxes. Your original code **hasErrors = !toCheck.val().length;** did just find for the boxes but not for the checkbox.

Comment: Um, did you change the jQuery-`$` to `document.getElementById`? Code for jQuery-elements would be like `$toCheck.is(":checkbox") ? $toCheck.prop("checked") : $toCheck.val()`

Comment: I copied just like you had it above in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This one is better to set CSS:

```
$('#error1').css({'display': 'none', 'visibility': 'hidden'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the short way of setting the CSS, keaukraine!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you could create css classes and use the [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function in jQuery

**Examaple:**

**CSS**

```
.hide{
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#error1').addClass("hide");
```

Comment: I've thought about doing that but still just wanted to use just one CSS class.

Comment: You could use `hide` class and set it when appropriate, and instead of having a new class you could use the `removeClass` function that jQuery also offers.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote your code

```
 $('#error3').css('display', 'block');
 $('#error3').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Repeats at several places for style change. Can you make it into a function such that you pass the error field name.

For `#error3` you pass the param as 3, then the display and visibility params.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the ids based on the value of whichToCheck and use jQuery's hide method to hide the elements:

```
function toggleErrors($input, whichToCheck){
  if($input.val() !== '' || $input.is(':checked')){
    $('#error' + whichToCheck).hide();
  }else{
    $('#error' + whichToCheck).show();
  }
}
```

Pass in whichToCheck and the corresponding input element to the function.

Comment: This is correct but i also have a checkbox value in this as well.

Comment: I added the checked condition which is a bit of a hack. However, I'd encourage you to use relations in order to connect the inputs and error elements if possible.

Comment: What does **input** represent? should it be **this.value**?

Comment: You need to pass in the input to the function. If it is invoked from an event handler, you could use this.value.

Comment: You'll need to find the value of input using a switch like the other answers suggests, unless you can find a connection between inputs and errors other ways...such as DOM relations, but I can't help you with that as I don't know how your mark up looks like.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Switch() statements as mentioned By Armel.
2. Extract Show() & Hide() methods separately.

Here is the sample:

```
if (whichToCheck == 1) {
        if ($('#input_3').val().length) {
            Show('#error1');
            hasErrors = false;
        } else {
            Hide('#error1');
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (whichToCheck == 2) {
        if ($('#input_4').val().length) {
            Show('#error2');
            hasErrors = false;
        } else {
            Hide('#error2');
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (whichToCheck == 3) {
        if ($('#input_5').val().length) {
            Show('#error3');
            hasErrors = false;
        } else {
            Hide('#error3');
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (whichToCheck == 4) {
        if ($('#input_7_0').is(':checked')) {
            Show('#error4');
            hasErrors = false;
        } else {
            Hide('#error4');
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    } else if (whichToCheck == 5) {
        if ($('#input_6').val().length) {
            Show('#error5');
            hasErrors = false;
        } else {
            Hide('#error5');
            hasErrors = true;
        }
    }

    function Show(id) {

        $(id).show();

    }

    function Hide(id) {
        $(id).hide();
    }
```

Comment: So why then did you not implement the switch?

Comment: Here, I have mentioned to use Switch assuming that the person knows how to use. So, I didin explain howto use Switch. But I wanted to point out to move some sphagetti coding for Hide & Show to separate methods to take care of them. It was the context in my explanation and not 'use of Switch'.

Answer (score 1):

The key to shortening your code seems to be the source of the `whichToCheck` variable. Alternatively you can do this:

```
//...
if ( $('#input_' + whichToCheck).val().length ) {
    $('#error_' + whichToCheck).css ( { 'display' : 'none', 'visibility' : 'hidden' } );
} else {
    $('#error_' + whichToCheck).css ( { 'display' : 'block', 'visibility' : 'visible' } );        
}
```