# Javascript: Better way to write if/else statement? Maybe use array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to a million IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029089/alternative-to-a-million-if-statements)

I am new to programming so I know very little. (Sorry for posting a newbie question)

Here is my question.

I have used "if, else" statement to redirect users depending on their country like this.

```
if (country == 'US') {
  window.location=us
}  
else {
  if (country == 'GR') {  
    window.location=gr
  }
  else {
    // (repeated this for 5 times/5 different countries)
  }
}
```

Well, now, I need to redirect visitors to their states (i.e., California, Arizona, etc.).

The problem is, if I keep using if/else statement, I know I have to repeat this for 50 times and the javascript code will end up looking ridiculous.

I know there is a better way to do this.

Can anyone show how to replace multiple if/else statement into an array? Array should be used in a situation like this? Am I correct?

If I am wrong, can you please correct me & show me what other statement should be used instead?

Thank you & once again, I apologize for putting up such a newbie question.

Comment: Check out the switch statement.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is to create a map:

```
var countries = {
    US: us,
    GR: gr
};

window.location = countries[country];
```

This works because you can get an object's property using strings. For example, if you have an object with a foo property:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.foo = 4;
```

Then you can also get to `foo` this way:

```
var foosValue = myObject['foo'];
```

This is basically a very primitive hashmap, which is a common data structure in programming. This pattern is common in JavaScript.

Comment: It's probably worth adding a default/fall-back to this: `window.location = countries[country] || genericpage;` just in case the user's in a location for which the country-map has no assigned value.

Comment: Got it!!  I see that I need to use var/variables.  Thank you for answering this newb question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var redirect = { "US": "http:this", "GR" : "http:that };

window.location = redirect[country] || alert("what are you trying to achieve?");
```

Comment: +1 to Matt. Could there be a delay of +15 minutes on SO? I though I answered a question in 15 seconds. Not minutes.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  this works.  I've started learning javascript last night so I don't quite understand "var" yet but at least I can figure out how to use it.

Comment: 'var' declares a "local" variable. Without 'var' you are overwriting possibly a very important global variable used by your browser and/or extending the "search area" of the run time interpreter to find the label you are referring. That means performance penalty.