# Adding sound to shorthand if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently adding extra sounds to my game. The problem is I have a shorthand if statement like "?...:..." and don't know how I can add audio to it. If it is not possible how would I make it a normal if statement without making it crash.

```
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    })
```

So if "wordglow3" I want to add "hit.play()" and for "wordglow" I want to add "miss.play()"

Comment: What do you mean by "adding sounds"? Can you give us an example how you would do it without any conditions?

Comment: The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) makes an expression, not a statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first the obvious solution with if/else-statements:

```
var c = b.clone();
if ( b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ) {
    c.addClass("wordglow3");
    hit.play();
} else {
    c.addClass("wordglow");
    miss.play();
}
c.appendTo(table).css(…);
```

Now, we could remove some duplicate code using variables:

```
var className, sound;
if ( b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ) {
    className = "wordglow3";
    sound = hit;
} else {
    className = "wordglow";
    sound = miss;
}
b.clone().addClass(className).appendTo(table).css(…);
sound.play();
```

or even shorter by initialising them with the defaults:

```
var className, = "wordglow",
    sound = miss;
if ( b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ) {
    className += "";
    sound = hit;
}
…
```

Using the ternary operator gets harder. We could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to chain different actions in the same expression:

```
b.clone().addClass( b.data("letter") == target.data("letter")
  ? hit.play(), "wordglow3"
  : miss.play(), "wordglow"
).appendTo(table).css(…);
```

But this is ugly. A better choice would be using a variable for the condition and two ternary operators:

```
var success = b.data("letter") == target.data("letter");
b.clone().addClass(success ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo(table).css(…);
(success ? hit : miss).play();
```

Once we've got here, you even might consider an extra data structure for your sounds and class names, to [replace millions of (especially nested) if-statements with selection by key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029116/1048572):

```
// global:
var sounds = { // or use an arrays
    "0": …, // miss
    "1": …  // hit
};
var classes = {
    "0": "wordglow",
    "1": "wordglow3"
};
// […]
// then, select values by casting the boolean to numeric keys:
var success = b.data("letter") == target.data("letter");
b.clone().addClass(classes[+success]).appendTo(table).css(…);
sounds[+success].play();
```

This makes extending your application with other cases easy, and allows an easier maintenance of used class names or sounds (in a central place) if they are used like this everywhere. Also, we've reduced two variables `hit` and `miss` to only one `sounds`.

Decide yourself which code snippet is best readable or most appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Which would you say is the best? @Bergi

Comment: "if + default variables" is best readable for beginners, "two ternary operators" even more concise and shorter (does not need variables) - my personal favourite. However, when beginning designing an application I'd always go with the last approach - I can understand that it won't integrate easily into already existing code.

Comment: Which would you say is easiest to integrate? @Bergi

Comment: C'mon, I don't know your code base; so you will decide yourself which one fits best in your current code.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had posted a fiddle. The problem is the 4th choice is the best suited but I have "}).animate" at the end and it won't seem to work @Bergi

Comment: Where do you have the `animate()`? Could you make a fiddle with your current code?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/11/ obviously because its a fiddle hit and miss will not play because they are stored locally. Watch out for the sound @Bergi

Comment: There's nothing wrong with solution #3: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/12/ Of course you also could put them after the longish start-animation-call.

Comment: The thing is now the letters dont animate when clicked @Bergi

Comment: Why, does `.play()` raise an exception? Or is it synchronous and lasts seconds?

Comment: OK, hadn't expected that. Then do http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/13/. However, I don't think it's possible to play synchronous sounds while something else (the animation) executes. If this is really the problem, ask an extra question on how to solve that

Comment: This wasn't the problem originally, only in your fiddles. My problem is that I want to add a sound so that when the animation hits the target it makes a sound dependent on whether it is right or wrong @Bergi

Comment: So the sound should play after the animation? Then move the statement into the animation's callback function

Comment: something like if $(b.data("letter") == target.data("letter")).hasClass('wordglow3') {
            hitSound.play();
            } else {
            missSound.play();
            }
            @Bergi

Comment: Why not just check the `success` variable we already have? Your code relies on a class name…

Comment: success and failure are different sounds already though. Hit and miss are different. I need them to be applied when wordglow and wordglow2 are @Bergi

Comment: I meant the boolean variable I introduced above, which also determines whether `wordglow3` or `wordglow` would be used. Of course you can rename it to something better.

Comment: I see. Could you show me a fiddle with the simple if, else version you showed? @Bergi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18728/discussion-between-milo-j-and-bergi)

Answer (score 0):

I mean if it is not working a shorthand way, you can just try the long way:

```
var class_to_add = "wordglow";
if(b.data("letter") == target.data("letter"))
  class_to_add = "wordglow3";
b.clone().addClass(class_to_add).appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    });
```

Comment: It works but I want to play a sound for each. So for "wordglow3" I want to play a sound called "hit" - hit.play() @Pulkit Mittal

Comment: You mean you wanna play audio from javascript? Then the question seems completely senseless, doesn't it?

Comment: Why is it senseless, if you read the question it says I want to add sound to each "wordglow" style @Pulkit Mittal