# Maximum conditions inside if in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there any maximum limit of conditions for `If` in Javascript? I am using following method to detect bombs in division "b". But it skips more than 3 or 4 conditions and hence less bombcount than the actual count.

The following function triggers as soon as I click on `div b` where `b = some number` . It has a Kwhere I check for bomb in every cell and if the cell with the bomb satisfies the position criterion it increases bombcount by 1.

```
    var i = 1;
    var p1 = b-1;
    var p2 = b+1;
    var p3 = b+6;
    var p4 = b-6;
    var p5 = b-5;
    var p6 = b+5;
    var p7 = b-7;
    var p8 = b+7;
    var bombcount = 0;

    while(i<37)
    {
        var check = document.getElementById(i).value;
        if (check == "explode" && b>6 && b<31) {
            if(i==p1 || i==p2 || i==p3 || i==p4 ||
               i==p5 || i==p6 || i==p7 || i==p8) {

               bombcount++
            };
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: No, there is no limit. If your code doesn't work as expect, you have to provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Your code looks not very good. Try to use array for `p1..p8` and if will looks like `if (array.indexOf(i) != -1)`

Comment: It might be a better idea to revisit your application's logic to avoid such conditionals.

Comment: there is no limit, but code looks not nice and hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array for `p` and indexOf to check is `i` in array:

```
var p = [b - 1, b + 1, b + 6, b - 6, b + 5, b - 5, b + 7, b - 7];
if (p.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
    bombcount++;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd advise to iterate over that `p` array instead of `i` and checking each element.

Comment: its the same thing in shorter version. It still deosn't gives me right answer. skips few positions. :(

Comment: @AbhishekUmrao: Then likely those `b-x` values are computed wrong. But if you can't tell us what they're supposed to be, we hardly can fix them.

Comment: @Bergi so `b-x` refer to the  adjacent cell numbers. I am trying to learn java by build minesweeper. its a 6x6 table.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that. Try to represent the table as an array of arrays, so that you can use two indizes for x and y position. There's going something wrong with your current calculations - step through it with a debugger and you'll see how you are checking the wrong fields.

Comment: Hey @Bergi thanks figured out what was going wrong `b+1` wasn't mathematically added but concatenate. Converting it to integer `b*1+1` solved the issue. Now it works like charm.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no limit to number of `if-else` statements, be it one after another or nested if-else loops. Also, there is as such no limit to number of condition you can have under a if statement.

But, it is better to use `switch` in those cases. It improves readability and performance.

For switch syntax see this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

For using switch over a range of values see this previous post
[Switch statement for greater-than/less-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than)

Comment: @Bergi why not ? Do you feel that because of range based comparisons ... well you can do that too... coding a bit cleverly, see the updated answer

Comment: Because he has one and the same action to take when a value matches, instead of many different ones. `switch` is a replacement for lots of [`if`-`else`-statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10029089/1048572) (and maybe not even the best one), but absolutely not for a single condition. Did you intend to use one huge fall-through?

Comment: @AurA how can you use `switch` here? it says if either of those conditions are satisfied then it will add to the bombcount.

Comment: The question is not about the number of if-else statements, but about the number of conditions inside an if ()

Comment: @finishingmove may be I misread it I have updated the answer for conditions too.

Comment: @AbhishekUmrao In your case switch might not be useful.. because you are checking only one if condition..

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit.  And as a tip, you maybe better off using `switch` and falling through for these conditions:

```
 switch (i)  {
     case p1:
     case p2:
     case p3:
             // your logic
             break;

 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch