# Is there a way to improve a large if/else or switch/case block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm refactoring some javascript to use jQuery and one of the events looks something like this

```
document.onkeyup = function keyUp(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 70) { // 'f'
    //Do something
}
else if (e.keyCode == 78) { // 'n'
    //Do something else
} ...
```

Unfortunately the things done in the cases aren't as similar or as simple as those in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640843/refactoring-a-large-block-of-chained-if-else-statements). Is there a better way to write this instead of a massive hard-coded if/else or switch/case statement?

Comment: It largely depends on what the "do something" is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to a million IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029089/alternative-to-a-million-if-statements)

Comment: Unfortunately the "do something" varies a bit (though there are a lot of simply loading urls at the moment) and I'd love to use something that is easily extensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's really better but you could list all of the possible values as keys of an object in some other dedicated file that you include. For example:

```
var keyHandlers = {
    "70": function () { /* Do something */ },
    "78": function () { /* Do something else */ }
};
```

Then, in your `keyup` event handler, you can simply refer to the appropriate property of this object:

```
document.onkeyup = function keyUp(e) {
    keyHandlers[e.keyCode]();
};
```

One notable disadvantage of this method over a `switch` statement would be that it'll look much messier if you want multiple keys to perform the same function. With a `switch`, you could just let those cases fall through. Here, you'll have to perform some other assignments after the inital `keyHandlers` declaration.

---

A couple of other points... you should use `addEventListener` rather than the `on...` properties, and is there a reason you've named the function you are assigning to `onkeyup` currently? The only reason to name it would be if you needed to refer to it from within itself.

Comment: Don't forget the `e.keyCode in keyHandlers` test.

Comment: Thanks! To answer your question, this was code written by someone else so I don't know why named it. I'm thinking of using something like $(document).on("keyup",this.keyUpHandler);

Answer (score 2):

Use an object to map key codes to functions:

```
var keyTable = {
  70: function () { ... },
  78: function () { ... },
  ... etc ...
}
```

Then your event handler becomes:

```
document.onkeyup = function keyUp(e) {
  keyTable[e.keyCode]();
};
```

Comment: Don't forget the `e.keyCode in keyTable` test.